# What is the correlation between self-rated and objective measures of intelligence?

Tags: intelligence, bias

In the context of a broader [question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/17365/52), someone asked:

> Can the detailed analyses from, say, the Wechsler test, be used to inform decisions significantly better that gut feelings can?

While this question might be closed, I thought a more defined question regarding the correlation between self-rated and objective measures of intelligence would be good to have. I feel as if I've read papers that suggest the correlation is modest (e.g., r = .2 or .3). Presumably, Dunning-Kruger and a bunch of self-serving biases operate. But I could not find any authoritative reference off hand. So my questions:

- What is the correlation between self-rated intelligence and objective measures of intelligence (i.e., full scale IQ scores from well-validated measures)?
- To what extent does the correlation depend on how the self-ratings are obtained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term you are looking for is [self-assessed intelligence (SAI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-test_of_intelligence) (sometimes subjectively-assessed intelligence or self-estimated intelligence).  The leaders in this field are Tomas Chamorro-Premuzic and Adrian Furnham.  From their book ["Personality and Intellectual Competence" (2014)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=M0t4AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=sai%20correlation%20to%20iq&source=bl&ots=mqs1DFXUd-&sig=qtrnZ3PobicGcUzlr0Bs3GaS2vQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh8PTv44fUAhVJ1oMKHc9LCSIQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=sai%20correlation%20to%20iq&f=false):

> Correlations between SAI and psychometric intelligence have been
>   significant and positive, albeit generally modest (r<.30).

So you are spot on. :-) SAI is a subset of self-tests of intelligence, that can range from simple estimates, to full-fledged self-administered IQ tests.  As such, correlations can vary a lot.  However, SAI is generally considered to be an estimate, rather than a test, and this does not appear to be affected much by methodology.  From [Paulhus et al (1998)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-6494.00023/abstract):

> Correlations between single-item self-reports of intelligence and IQ
>   scores are rather low (.20–.25) in college samples. The literature
>   suggested that self-reports could be improved by three strategies: (1)
>   aggregation, (2)item weighting, and (3) use of indirect, rather than
>   direct, questions. ... Although results showed some success for both
>   direct and indirect measures, the failure of their validities to
>   exceed .30 impugns their utility as IQ proxies in competitive college
>   samples.

On the other hand, the SAI literature reveals significant gender differences in SAI estimates - with males significantly overestimating and females significantly underestimating their intelligence - as well as significant cross-cultural differences in estimates, suggesting that the correlation is more heavily affected by social stereotypes.